# Dependency injection when using UnitOfWork pattern

Tags: inversion-of-control, unit-of-work

I'm trying to get my head around an existing system that is built upon the `UnitOfWork` pattern. There are a lot of repositories that all takes an `IUnitOfWork` in its constructor, so that the service layers can perform multiple repository calls and then choose when to commit the changes.

The current service code may look something like this:

```
using (var uow = UnitOfWork.Start())
{
    var orderRepository = new OrderRepository(uow);
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository(uow);
    orderRepository.DoSomething();
    productRepository.DoSomethingElse();
    uow.Persist();
}
```

How can I introduce true dependency injection in the service layer and still keep the `UnitOfWork` pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would use factory pattern. Inject factory in constructor and rewrite:

```
using (var uow = this.unitOfWorkFactory.Create().Start())
{
    var orderRepository = new OrderRepository(uow);
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository(uow);
    orderRepository.DoSomething();
    productRepository.DoSomethingElse();
    uow.Persist();
}
```

Best regards

Comment: Its the repositories I want to inject, the UnitOfWork class is not really the issue...

Comment: @Bjorn
Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

One solution would be that UnitOfWork holds concrete implementations of the repositories.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way to go. Its not ideal that the UoW knows about the repositories, but on the other hand, its easy to replace since its an interface, and its not too bad that the UoW is specific for the different repositories that it is trying to coordinate.